# Chrome failed to start: crashed. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) after upgrade to chrome 93.0.4577.63

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

This issue started after upgrade to 93.0.4577.63

I tried going back to chromedriver v 92.0.4515.107 but encountered the same issue.

I tried several fixes from similar posts (much older posts) like using --no-sandbox and other flags but no luck. Anyone else seeing this ?

````
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '', ip: '192.168.0.146', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: ECWebDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00672A33+2501171]
    Ordinal0 [0x0060D1C1+2085313]
    Ordinal0 [0x00511FA8+1056680]
    Ordinal0 [0x0052D07C+1167484]
    Ordinal0 [0x0052997F+1153407]
    Ordinal0 [0x0055999F+1350047]
    Ordinal0 [0x0055960A+1349130]
    Ordinal0 [0x0055551B+1332507]
    Ordinal0 [0x00531D74+1187188]
    Ordinal0 [0x00532BD9+1190873]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007EEFE6+1504438]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0089DDA5+2220661]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006F5589+481881]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006F4639+477961]
    Ordinal0 [0x006128BD+2107581]
    Ordinal0 [0x00616728+2123560]
    Ordinal0 [0x00616862+2123874]
    Ordinal0 [0x0061FA81+2161281]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75BCFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A4E+238]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157) ```
````

Comment: I have the exact same error with Edge. Chrome is working fine. Tried all I could find in SO but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

For the Chrome Web driver to function it needs to be compatible with the version of Chrome installed on the machine that you are executing.

Please go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and download the ChromeDriver version compatible with the Chrome installation on your machine. For the version, you mentioned it will be ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.15.

Comment: Thank you but that is the first thing i tried. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Guess in the wild, because that was our problem:

We started with some `options`, then converted them via `capabilities = options.to_capabilities()` and then we initialized `Chrome` only with those `capabilities`. But somehow you now have to also provide the original `options` to take effect.

So instead of

```
driver = Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

we now have to do

```
driver = Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```